# Redirecting to Non-SEO Friendly Url

Tags: category, url-rewrite, enterprise-1.14

I have upgraded my Magento store from *EE 1.11* to *EE 1.14*

***Problem***

After upgrade I have changed URL key for one category. Now on frontend it is showing me correct URL on mouse hover but when I am clicking on that category link it is showing non-SEO friendly URL in address bar.

***Example :***

Suppose SEO friendly url is `mydomain.com/category-parent/category-sub.html`,  but instead of this, it is showing `mydomain.com/catalog/category/view/id/84` in address bar.

***What I have done***

I have cleared all caches and re-indexed all data.

It would be great if someone can help me out in fixing this issue.

Comment: Is it just one category doing this or all?

Comment: @DavidManners -- Only categories for which I have changed the url keys.

Comment: I have a similar issue. Did you find a solution to yours? I appreciate any advice on [this question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/317644/404-and-non-seo-friendly-urls-in-html-docs-despite-having-core-url-rewrite-entri)

Answer (score 1):

If your upgrade went without any errors. See:

- http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/install/installing_upgrade_landing.html

Then performing a full reindex, and then clear of all caches should solve the issue.  Also make sure indexes are set to update on save.

Answer (score 0):

So the only thing I can think of is that Magento changed the way url rewrites are stored between some version.

I know that in 1.13 there was a set of scripts to migrate urls from one system to the other.

Have a look at the scripts:

- `shell/url_migration_to_1_13.php`
- `shell/url_migration_from_1_13_0_0_to_1_13_0_2.php`

You may find that running these scripts will solve the problem but you may also need to upgrade Magento in steps. So 1.11 to 1.13 then 1.13 to 1.13.0.2 then 13.0.2 to 1.14